# Codeigniter - SQL error. Driving me crazy

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, codeigniter

Here is my code:

$child = $this->getDetails($row['ParentOf_Id']);

which is in another function that calls a function called getdetails:

function getDetails($child_id=null,$limit=20){

```
    // select all the fields in the children table
    $this->db->select(castedColumns($this->children_table, $this->db));
    //where the id is the child id
    $q = $this->db->get_where($this->children_table, 'id='.$child_id);
    //store results array in details
    $details = $q->row_array();
```

I then get the following SQL error:

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number:

Incorrect syntax near '='.

SELECT CAST(AdditionalNotes AS TEXT) as AdditionalNotes, CAST(DisabilitiesNotes AS TEXT) as DisabilitiesNotes, DOB, msrepl_tran_version FROM Children WHERE id=

Id does not get appended? why?

Been driving me nuts because, when I do echo $child_id; I get the child Id before passing it into the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
$this->db->select(castedColumns($this->children_table, $this->db));
$q = $this->db->get_where($this->children_table, array('id' => $child_id));
$details = $q->row_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that $child_id is null, otherwise it would show in the db error query. Try to print $child_id and see if it's really a null which would mean that

```
 $child = $this->getDetails($row['ParentOf_Id']);
```

$row['ParentOf_Id'] is null.

Comment: Got it working, $child_id=null changed to $child_id and mikhail solution seemed to have done the trick. Cheers.